# Are there different Encoding Conventions for Base64?

Tags: linux, encoding, base64

I am wondering if there are specifically different coding conventions for Base64? In other words, is there any reason why two different Base64 encoders should produce two different outputs for the same file?

The reason I ask is because I am scanning one JPEG and I am getting two different Base64 codes.

The first encoder I am using is [base64image.org](http://base64image.org/)

The second encoder is by executing the following command in a Linux environment:

```
openssl base64 -e -in alps.jpg  > B64EncodedFile
```

I have verified the legitimacy of both encoders by decoding the Base64 code back into a JPEG and finding that it is identical to the original JPEG

Comment: You really ought to do basic research, such as searching Google. The first hit is the [Wikipedia article on Base-64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) which gives all the common variants (they differ only in the index 62 and 63 characters).

Answer (score 2):

Base64 just states that the alphabet for representing data is composed of 64 unique characters. They can be any characters. These two different sources are simply using different alphabets. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) for more details.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, and its not right. with that same backwards logic you can state that ASCII can conceivably be composed of Chinese characters. Or binary can be T/F rather than 1/0. If what you say is true, I'd be surprised that any decoder works considering encoders all use different alphabets.
 
Wikipedia answered my question. I read it last week and didn't remember reading that. Also, when I googled it, nothing came up. Interesting...

Comment: @user3875135 Your statement would be true, if ASCII = Unicode. However, it doesn't. I would refer you to the academic literature on character encodings, in this case a good starting point is, again, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii). As for the Base64, if you read the link I kindly provided, you would see that what I state is indeed true. From the page, "The particular choice of character set selected for the 64 characters required for the base varies between implementations." [Base64 Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Design).